# Trying insert data to database by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I want to insert data on table dbo.batch but but I have an error message when i tried to insert the data

error message

> Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

[image: should be code here]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: What does the error message say? (The image text is too small for me to read.)

Comment: *The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement* - What is not clear in this message?

Comment: I question your choice of supplying only a time to the column "schedule_datetime" as well as supplying only dates to the other "datetime" columns. But unrealistic sample data is a different issue. Seems like you did not include "update_at" in the column list.

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 columns in your statement but 11 values to enter. Therefore the error message

Answer (score 0):

You have 10 columns and you are inserting 11 values check for the valid columns values you need and remove other.

I guess the last 2nd column value is the one you should remove